# How To Insert Multiple Page Break In Microsoft Word After Specific Line Using VBA Macros?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word Document with about 100 pages and I want to print it page by page as I copied in in Word from TXT File. So the concept in TXT file page break was a line as shared below...

`--------------------------------------------Continue on next page------------------------------------------------`

Now I want to do some automation about this Page-Break in word because I can't make it manually. SO I want some VBA Script as MACROS to search this specific line and then add Page-Break after this.

[image]

So Is this possible via VBA as I tried and got no way in Word Toolbar Features and tried to use upper screenshot feature but it is only adding page-break after highlighted line.

Here is the MACRO that I tried to RUn and I wrote it by the help of other queries over Stack Overflow but it's not working...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FindAndAddPageBreak()
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim MyWordDocument As Word.Document
    Dim Counter As Long
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application
    Set MyWordDocument = Word.Application.Documents.Open("C:\test.docx")
    For Counter = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sentences.Count
        With MyWordDocument.Sentences(Counter)
            If Left$(.Text, 11) = "--------------------------------------------Continue on next page------------------------------------------------" Then
                Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

**Alternative Solution:**
Thanks to [macropod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9170274/macropod) for the hint via GUI. Search & Replace is the option but it is giving me only BEFORE not AFTER. SO what about AFTER?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You most likely got downvoted because you've shown no coding or other problem-solving effort of your own. It is quite easy to use Find/Replace - without recourse to VBA - to change your 'Continue on next page' markers to actual page breaks (or to insert actual page breaks after them, if that's what you want).

Comment: @macropod Code added what I tried and not working.

Comment: @macropod Your hint to use GUI option in Word is acceptable but with half answer. Can you share any alternative to add PAGE BREAK AFTER required texts around the document? (Many are searching these type of queries so your vote up will help others to find this helpful too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace with:

```
Find = Continue on next page[!^13]@^13
Replace = ^&^12
```

Comment: Thanks. This trick worked... (Many are searching these types of queries so your vote up to question will help others to find this helpful too)